# python implementation of multiple objects localization loss (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I'm currently trying to find any information on how to implement localization loss within the task of detection of multiple objects on an image. There are a lot of information on how to calculate localization loss if there is only one detection. From the other hand, there are also lots of implementations of sota object detectors (RCNN, F-RDCC, SSD etc).

The reason of my question is that I would like to try to train custom object detector which output is a simple tensor of shape B x N x 4, without any anchors and so on.

So, if I understand correctly, to calculate multiple objects loss one have to first map each perdition to ground truth bounding box (using for instance IoU) and than calculate smooth L1 loss for each pair and average them. How to do it within tensorflow?

Thanks in advance.